# How defragment compressed partitioned table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, disk-space, fragmentation

I have partitioned table by day with compressed query high option for partitions in Oracle 11.2 database.

Delete by key and direct insert was used to populate a data for the table. So the table is fragmented currently.

As I know from Oracle documentation the shrink space can not be applied to compressed tables.

I performed next actions

```
alter table order nocompress;
alter table order enable row movement;
alter table order MODIFY PARTITION SYS_P21674395 nocompress;
....
```

Also checked the autoextensible for table space

```
select tablespace_name, file_name, autoextensible from dba_data_files
where tablespace_name='DEV_ODS_DATA'
```

DEV_ODS_DATA    datafile/dev_ods_data.878.1079624941    YES

```
select * from dba_tab_partitions where table_name='order';
```

all partitions compression is disabled

also

```
select iot_type,compression from user_tables where table_name='order';
```

iot_type=NULL; compression=NULL

When I trying to perform

```
ALTER TABLE order SHRINK SPACE compact;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE order MODIFY PARTITION SYS_P21674395 SHRINK SPACE;
```

I get the next error

```
ALTER TABLE order MODIFY PARTITION SYS_P21674395 SHRINK SPACE
Error report -
ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type
10635. 00000 -  "Invalid segment or tablespace type"
*Cause:    Cannot shrink the segment because it is not in auto segment space
           managed tablespace or it is not a data, index or lob segment.
*Action:   Check the tablespace and segment type and reissue the statement
```

The table does not have FUNCTION based indexes

Do the exists approach to shrink space for the table without table recreating?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162415/how-to-shrink-space-on-table-with-a-function-based-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOCOMPRESS` does not decompress existing data in a table/partition, it applies only to new data inserted later. You can leave original compression method unchanged.

You can `MOVE` a partition:

```
ALTER TABLE order MOVE PARTITION SYS_P21674395 UPDATE INDEXES;
```

This is not a fully online operation, meaning the data in the partition can not be modified during the move.

If you were on version 12.1 or higher, you could use `MOVE ONLINE`:

```
ALTER TABLE order MOVE PARTITION SYS_P21674395 ONLINE UPDATE INDEXES;
```

`MOVE` will copy and recompress (given that the compression method was set) the partition then drop the old segment.

You can also specify the compression method in the `MOVE` command:

```
ALTER TABLE order MOVE PARTITION SYS_P21674395 
  COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH UPDATE INDEXES;
```

Comment: OP may not have Exadata or IM, so "FOR QUERY HIGH" wouldn't work for them.

Comment: @PaulW In the first sentence in the question *I have partitioned table by day **with compressed query high** option*.

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
-- uncompress partition
  ALTER TABLE DEV_DW.TEST_TABLE move PARTITION SYS_P21822227 NOCOMPRESS UPDATE INDEXES;  

--required for shrink space
  ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE enable row movement;

--Shrink the partition to reclaim unused space
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE MODIFY PARTITION SYS_P21822227 SHRINK SPACE;


--compress partition
ALTER TABLE DEV_DW.TEST_TABLE move PARTITION SYS_P21822227 COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH  UPDATE INDEXES; 

--gather stats
 BEGIN
DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('DEV_DW', 'TEST_TABLE',
                                     estimate_percent=>dbms_stats.auto_sample_size,
                                     block_sample=>TRUE,
                                     degree=>8) ;
END;
commit;

--test

  select 
  table_owner
  ,table_name
  ,partition_name
  ,high_value
  ,compression
  ,compress_for
  ,avg_row_len
  ,round(((blocks*16/1024)),2)/1024 "TOTAL_SIZE_GB" --The amount of space used by the partition in gigabytes.
  ,round((num_rows*avg_row_len/1024/1024),2)/1024 "ACTUAL_SIZE_GB" -- The amount of space used by the partition in gigabytes, calculated based on the number of rows and the average row length.
  ,round(((blocks*16/1024)-(num_rows*avg_row_len/1024/1024)),2)/1024 "FRAGMENTED_SPACE_GB" --The amount of space that is not used by the partition, in gigabytes.
  ,decode(round(((blocks*16/1024)),2),0,0, (round(((blocks*16/1024)-(num_rows*avg_row_len/1024/1024)),2)/round(((blocks*16/1024)),2))*100) "percentage" --The percentage of unused space in the partition, calculated by dividing the unused space by the total space and multiplying by 100. 
from dba_tab_partitions 
WHERE 
1=1
and table_owner='DEV_DW'
and table_name='TEST_TABLE'
and partition_name='SYS_P21822227'
and round(((blocks*16/1024)-(num_rows*avg_row_len/1024/1024)),2)/1024 > 0
order by 6 desc
;
```

Comment: It makes no sense to do this. Just `ALTER TABLE DEV_DW.TEST_TABLE move PARTITION SYS_P21822227 UPDATE INDEXES;  ` will do it. There is no need to do 2 MOVE + 1 SHRINK operations.

Comment: @BalazsPapp why shink space is not required?

Comment: As I have already written: MOVE alone copies and recompresses the partition.

Comment: @BalazsPapp ok then question next. Does the move command reorganize blocks and makes defragmentation as well?

Comment: `MOVE` creates a new copy of the segment, compresses and reorganizes data, then drops the old segment.